# React onSelect event not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

Does React have an event handler for the onSelect statement? i.e. if a user selects some text with their mouse within a paragraph (highlighted text) trigger an event that extracts the selected text.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ReadModule extends Component {
  selectedText() {
      console.log("You selected some text");
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <div id="read-module" className="row">
            <p>Reading:</p>
            <span onSelect={this.selectedText}>{this.props.reading}</span>
          </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ReadModule;
```

The above doesn't work. If there is an approach that is better i.e. extracting a string please do let me know! Once i get a simple

> on highlight trigger function

Concept working I can take it from there. Thanks in advance

**Solution:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ReadModule extends Component {
  selectedText() {
        var txt = "";
        if (window.getSelection) {
                txt = window.getSelection();
        }
        else if (document.getSelection) {
            txt = document.getSelection();
        } else if (document.selection) {
            txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
        }

        alert("Selected text is " + txt);
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <div id="read-module" className="row">
            <p>Reading:</p>
            <span onMouseUp={this.selectedText}>{this.props.reading}</span>
          </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ReadModule;
```

Comment: I might be mistaken but AFAIK onSelect only works for input fields and textboxes, not for a span. You'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: hey bro, I used your solution this is working fine but I guess the first if part is enough to get the selected text, why did you add the other two else statement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/ydeshayes/react-highlight

To get the effect you want with a regular DOM element involves a lot of delicate code handling mouse events.

You could cheat and use an `<input>` or `<textarea>` instead and style it to look like regular text. Then `onSelect` should just work.

Comment: Is cheating with an input or textarea acceptable for an application that will go into production, kind of hesitant if it exposes the application to vulnerabilities. Whats your take?

Comment: Well you'd want to give the input a `readonly` attribute. As long as your input is not wired up to anything I don't see a cause for concern. Of course if you could make it work with the `<span>` then its even better.

Comment: Uncaught Error: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Comment: `<input>` takes its body text like this `<input value="abcdefg" />`. `<textarea>` is probably an easier fit for you.

Answer (score 1):

React has this option. In my opinion You have to bind function to this key word:

```
onSelect={this.selectedText.bind(this)}
```

So, Your code will look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ReadModule extends Component {
  selectedText() {
      console.log("You selected some text");
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <div id="read-module" className="row">
            <p>Reading:</p>
            <span onSelect={this.selectedText.bind(this)}>{this.props.reading}</span>
          </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ReadModule;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. i did selectedText(e) { console.log(e) }. This returns a proxy. Now i'm not sure what this is, but is this right approach to extracting the selected value?

Comment: hey! just so you know, you don't need to use `bind` if you declare the `selectedText` function like so:

```selectedText = () => {
}```

Comment: Does this really work? In my case, `<span>` or `<div>` tag doesn't fire onSelect event. It is fired such as `<textarea>` tag for me.